# Editors to draw diagrams in Unified Modeling Language?

Tags: uml

I was wondering how you draw diagrams in Unified Modeling Language for your project design? By hand on paper or some editors on computer? It will be great if there are some convenient editors or other gadgets for help. I am programming under Windows and Ubuntu.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Should be "community wiki" because this seems to be a poll, rather than a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reverse the java project and then just drag and drop from the Package Explorer to the diagram. When I have finished to present the existing classes I then add UML classes in the diagram. No code generation or model driven, just UML graphical representation mixing existing classes and abstract classes. I give my diagrams to the team and let them integrate it.

**I am very lazy when modeling :-)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/reverse/reverse/drag_drop_package_explorer_to_diagram.png))</sub>

I can see my classes and navigate from one package to another showing associations, inheritances and dependencies dynamically. No need to create a diagram per view, I prefer to use the show hide links and directly navigate in the java code and model from the same diagram it is easier and a lot more powerful because interactive.

[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/class_diagram_from_rsa.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/dependencies_view.png))</sub>

[image]

Just using the class contextual menu I can navigate. Really cool

[image]
<sub>(source: [forum-omondo.com](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/show_all_inheritance.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I used [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/).

Comment: Me too! I'm using it for school right now as I type this comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I used [Poseidon for UML](http://www.gentleware.com/) for quite a while.. not that bad, it's just a little bit slow since it's written in Java.

If I remember correctly it also has a community license that can be obtained for free..

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for **StarUML**
maybe its not brand new, but it does the job!

It works under Windows.

[read more about StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried StartUML and there is no java integration !! 
You can certainly reverse basic code but not the full project (e.g; over 50% of important information is missing) , the graphical editor is UML 1;x and not UML 2.x and for me this project is dead because no more update since more than 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

I use Dia for my diagramming needs.  It's open source and [cross](http://dia-installer.de/index_en.html) [platform](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) so you can switch between OS's without worrying about which format your diagrams were in.  It exports to several different image types and has a [Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/dia_portable) version (for Windows) as well.